# Use jQuery to apply styling to all instances of clicked element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, selection, element

What I'm aiming for is for jQuery to look at the element I've just clicked on (for example a p or an li tag), then apply a styling to all instances of that element (so all p tags on the page).

This is my code so far, but it only applies the styling to the single element that has been clicked on.

```
$("article *", document.body).click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
selectedElement = $(this);
$(selectedElement).css("border", "1px dotted #333")
});
```

Would appreciate any help or advice!

Comment: Avoid using the wildcard selector `*` to assign handlers. There's often another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('article *',document.body).click(
function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var selectedElement = this.tagName;
    $(selectedElement).css('border','1px dotted #333');
}
);
```

Demo at [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/axeki3/2/), albeit I've used the universal selector (since I only posted a couple of lists (one an `ol` the other a `ul`).

Above code edited in response to comments from @Peter Ajtai, and linked JS Bin demo up-dated to reflect the change:

> Why run around the block once before you look at the tagName? How about var selectedElement = this.tagName;. Also it's e.stopPropagation(), since you're calling a method.

Comment: Why run around the block once before you look at the `tagName`? How about `var selectedElement = this.tagName;`. Also it's `e.stopPropagation()`, since you're calling a method.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how many elements are nested under your `article` elements, but it would seem wasteful to add click event handlers to *all* of them using `*`.

Instead, just add the handler to `article`, and get the `tagName` of the `e.target` that was clicked.

```
$("article", document.body).click(function ( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $( e.target.tagName ).css("border", "1px dotted #333")
});
```

This will be *much* more efficient.